# What is wrong with the syntax?

Tags: mysql, create-table

```
CREATE TABLE Existing_medical_condition (
    condition VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    date_of_diagnosis DATE, treatment TEXT, 
    pssn INT NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT emc_key PRIMARY KEY(condition, pssn), 
    FOREIGN KEY(pssn) REFERENCES Patient(ssn)
);
```

Gives error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, date_of_diagnosis DATE, treatment TEXT, pssn INT' at line 1

Comment: If any of the answers below were helpful, please consider accepting them as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

Condition is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html). You must encase it in backticks:

```
CREATE TABLE Existing_medical_condition (
    `condition` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    date_of_diagnosis DATE, 
    treatment TEXT, 
    pssn INT NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT emc_key 
    PRIMARY KEY(condition, pssn), 
    FOREIGN KEY(pssn) REFERENCES Patient(ssn));
```

Comment: I thought is was [condition], but I would just stay away from reserved words.

Comment: @JBrooks Square brackets are for MSSQL.

Comment: Even though you can use reserved words with backticks, it is usually not the best idea to do so, because sooner or later you will run into trouble. I would suggest using `condition_name` or something like that.

Comment: Thank you. I chose to go with condition_name.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid reserved keywords for column names. If you still want you can write below.

```
CREATE TABLE Existing_medical_condition ([condition] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,     date_of_diagnosis DATE, treatment TEXT, 
pssn INT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT emc_key PRIMARY KEY(condition, pssn), FOREIGN KEY(pssn)       REFERENCES Patient(ssn));
```